# How many titan shifters can harden their skin?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I've just watched the anime series and in it, we've just seen the female titan and the armored titan being able to harden their skin. But reading in the internet I've found that

> In the manga Eren can harden his skin and so does the Beast Titan

is there any other titan shifters who can harden their skin? How many titan shifters can harden their skin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link explains all the abilities of every Titan :-

[Titan Abilities](https://www.animeshirtclub.com/blogs/news/attack-on-titan-all-9-titan-shifters-powers-explained)

The titans that can Harden are :-

1. Beast Titan
2. Female Titan
3. Armoured Titan(dunno if you can call this hardening but he has hardened skin afterall!!).
4. Attack Titan

Answer (score 0):

I think all titans have the potential to harden their skin either by learning, such as Annie and Zeke, or through a serum, such as Eren. Some may also be able to do it through command as the founding titan forced many colossal titans to harden their skin to make all 3 walls, these titans were not shifters but still had the ability to harden their skin under the control of the the king.